# Instantiate an object after getJSON is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oop

I want to instantiate a new object from the data fetched by another object in a jQuery getJSON call. I discovered promise objects, and I thought I might be able to use them to accomplish this. Here's my implementation:

```
function HeadlineList(url) {
    this.url = url;

    this.checkEmpty = function() {
        if (this.quantity === 0) {
            this.refreshContent();
        }
    };

    this.getRandom = function(remove) {
        var headlineNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*this.quantity);
        var headlinePick = this.list[headlineNumber];
        if (remove) {
            this.deleteHeadline(headlineNumber);
        }
        return headline;
    };

    this.getHeadline = function(number, remove) {
        var headlinePick = this.list[number]
        if (remove) {
            this.deleteHeadline(number);
        }
        return headline;
    };

    this.deleteHeadline = function(number) {
        this.list.splice(number, 1);
        this.quantity -= 1;
    };

    this.fillFromJSON = function(data) {
        this.list = data.headlines;
        this.quantity = this.list.length;
    };

    // Here's where I create the promise object. 'response' is globally 
    // scoped so my other objects can get to it.
    this.refreshContent = function() {
        response = $.when($.getJSON(this.url, this.fillFromJSON));
    };

    this.refreshContent();
}
```

When a `HeadlineList` object is instantiated, it fetches data using getJSON. This AJAX request is stored in the `response` global variable so I can make sure it's done later. After this, I want a different object created, but the data depends on this `HeadlineList` being properly instantiated. I tried using the `done` method of `response` to accomplish this.

The class in question:

```
function Headline(object) {
    this.title = object.title;
    this.url = object.url;
    this.onion = object.onion;

    this.isOnion = function(){
        return this.onion;
    }
}
```

And the instantiation of the class after instantiating a `HeadlineList` object:

```
// headlines is an instance of HeadlineList with the URL of my JSON file. 
// It should (and does) make the request when instantiated.
headlines = new HeadlineList('js/headlines.json');

// Instantiating the headline after the AJAX request is done. Passing
// a random headline from the HeadlineList object to the constructor.
response.done(function() {
    headline = new Headline(headlines.getRandom(true));
});
```

I've looked at the Chrome DevTools Network tab to be sure there's nothing wrong with the JSON file. It's giving a 200 response and validates in a JSON linter. The `list` property of the `headlines` object should contain the data from the file, but it is always undefined. The program hits an exception on this line inside the `headlines` object's `getRandom` method:

```
var headlinePick = this.list[headlineNumber];
```

The exception is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined`.

I'm not sure where the problem is exactly or where to go from here. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` won't mean the `headlines` object when called directly from `getJSON`.

Try:

```
this.refreshContent = function() {
    var self = this;
    response = $.when($.getJSON(this.url,
      function(data) {
        self.fillFromJSON(data);
      }
    );
};
```

Comment: Or more simply `response = $.when($.getJSON(this.url, this.fillFromJSON.bind(this)));`

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you both!